# Multicast packets going missing in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, multicast

I have a networked thermostat on my home network. It sends out multicast packets every so often to update listening devices on its status (temperature, mode etc). I have two PCs on the network too: a desktop PC running Windows 7 and a laptop running Windows 8.1. Both are connected at the same point in the network. I have written a program in C# to receive the packets and display their contents. I've tried running it on each PC. Running wireshark on each PC, I can see the packets arriving at each PC. My code is catching the packets on the Win 7 PC but not on the Win 8.1 PC. Can anyone think why this might be?

Here is my code for setting up the port/client:

```
multicast_udp = new UdpClient();
multicast_udp_ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, xxxxx);

multicast_udp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
multicast_udp.Client.Bind(multicast_udp_ep);

IPAddress multicastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
multicast_udp.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddress);

multicast_udp.BeginReceive(Multicast_UDP_IncomingData, null);
```

I've done a bit of debugging (I've put some MessageBox.Show commands in) and I've found that on the Win 7 machine, Multicast_UDP_Incoming Data is being called, but on the Win 8.1 machine it isn't.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check that Port `xxxxx` is enabled on the Win 8.1 firewall.

Comment: Thank you. That sorted it. There were blocking rules in there for my application. No idea how they got there!

Comment: Windows will "do that for your protection" when an unknown program attempts to access ports.